What determine if an application is closed when restarting in windows 11
For example, if I restart my windows 11 laptop which is running Notepad and Terminal, after restarting, the instance of Notepad is still running but the instance of Terminal was closed. What is causing this different behavior. How can I predict if an application will be closed by the restart action?
